# Filtering API response using axios with Vue.js

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

```
// this is my method    
filterProducts() {
      axios
        .get("http://fake-api.ns.nsdevel.eu/products")
        .then((resp3) => {this.products = resp3.data.products})
        .catch((error) => {
          this.errorMessage = error.message;
          console.error("There was an error!", error);
        });
    },
```

I want to filter those products based on the companies. Can someone give me a hint? I tried many times but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
filterProducts(companyName) {
      axios
        .get("http://fake-api.ns.nsdevel.eu/products")
        .then((resp3) => {this.products = resp3.data.products.filter(x => x.company.name == companyName)})
        .catch((error) => {
          this.errorMessage = error.message;
          console.error("There was an error!", error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: and if I want to to filter not only companies but also categories?

Comment: Assuming you have a `categoryIds` parameter, you can do it this way:

`resp3.data.products.filter(x => x.company.name == companyName || x.categories.some(cat => categoryIds.includes(cat.id)))
`